# The SVG Blobs are not animating when used with keyframes rule

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to implement a simple blob animation in the main page of my website. I am
able to see the first blob svg but the animation does not seem to be working. Thanks in advance for all answers. I'm copy pasting my HTML & CSS rules here.

HTML:

```
                <div class="intro-img col-lg-6">
                    <div class="blob">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="blob" width="600">
                            <path fill="#FE17A2" d="M59.1,-33.9C71.6,-12.5,73.4,15.4,61.7,35.4C50.1,55.4,25,67.5,-1.8,68.6C-28.7,69.6,-57.4,59.7,-69.8,39.2C-82.3,18.7,-78.5,-12.2,-64.1,-34.7C-49.8,-57.2,-24.9,-71.2,-0.8,-70.8C23.3,-70.3,46.6,-55.3,59.1,-33.9Z" transform="translate(100 100)" />
                        </svg>                              
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.intro-img{
    height: 90vh;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#blob{
    animation : blob 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blob {
    0%{
        d : path("M67.2,-41.6C78.5,-19.4,72.9,9.7,58.9,34.3C44.8,58.9,22.4,78.9,-0.9,79.4C-24.2,79.9,-48.5,61,-59.4,38.2C-70.3,15.4,-67.9,-11.2,-55.8,-33.9C-43.6,-56.6,-21.8,-75.5,3.1,-77.2C28,-79,56,-63.8,67.2,-41.6Z");
    }
    25%{
        d : path("M68.3,-38.6C82.6,-14.7,84.2,17.4,70.6,38.1C57.1,58.7,28.6,68,2.4,66.6C-23.7,65.2,-47.4,53.1,-60,32.9C-72.7,12.8,-74.3,-15.5,-62.4,-38C-50.6,-60.4,-25.3,-77.1,0.9,-77.6C27,-78.1,54.1,-62.4,68.3,-38.6Z");
    }
    50%{
        d : path("M65.4,-37C79.1,-14.1,80.5,16.6,67.5,37C54.6,57.5,27.3,67.8,0,67.8C-27.3,67.8,-54.6,57.5,-66.3,37.8C-78,18,-74.1,-11.3,-60.5,-34.2C-46.8,-57,-23.4,-73.5,1.2,-74.2C25.9,-74.9,51.8,-59.9,65.4,-37Z");
    }
    75%{
        d : path("M57.1,-35.2C68.5,-13.3,68.3,13,56.8,32.4C45.4,51.9,22.7,64.4,-1.4,65.2C-25.6,66.1,-51.2,55.2,-63,35.5C-74.9,15.9,-73,-12.6,-60.2,-35.3C-47.4,-58,-23.7,-74.9,-0.4,-74.7C22.9,-74.4,45.8,-57,57.1,-35.2Z");
    }
    100%{
        d : path("M67.2,-41.6C78.5,-19.4,72.9,9.7,58.9,34.3C44.8,58.9,22.4,78.9,-0.9,79.4C-24.2,79.9,-48.5,61,-59.4,38.2C-70.3,15.4,-67.9,-11.2,-55.8,-33.9C-43.6,-56.6,-21.8,-75.5,3.1,-77.2C28,-79,56,-63.8,67.2,-41.6Z");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, when writing the animation rule for the blob include path (the one you are trying to animate here) to the selector so instead of using:

```
#blob{
    animation : blob 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Use:

```
#blob path{
    animation: blob 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Why accept the other answer instead of yours? They didn't even add any explanation about what was wrong.

Comment: just wanted to get a solution that's all. Plus it says I have to wait for 2 days :|

Comment: Sure but you found that solution. The vote system is made to help other readers find out which content is worthy of their attention. By misusing it you're sending the signal that posting poor quality answers is not even fine but rewarded.

Comment: Hey @Kaiido thanks for pointing this out. I'll make sure that these things won't happen again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
.intro-img{
    height: 90vh;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#blob path {
    animation : blob 5s linear infinite;    
    
}

@keyframes blob {
    0%{
        d : path("M67.2,-41.6C78.5,-19.4,72.9,9.7,58.9,34.3C44.8,58.9,22.4,78.9,-0.9,79.4C-24.2,79.9,-48.5,61,-59.4,38.2C-70.3,15.4,-67.9,-11.2,-55.8,-33.9C-43.6,-56.6,-21.8,-75.5,3.1,-77.2C28,-79,56,-63.8,67.2,-41.6Z");
    }
    25%{
        d : path("M68.3,-38.6C82.6,-14.7,84.2,17.4,70.6,38.1C57.1,58.7,28.6,68,2.4,66.6C-23.7,65.2,-47.4,53.1,-60,32.9C-72.7,12.8,-74.3,-15.5,-62.4,-38C-50.6,-60.4,-25.3,-77.1,0.9,-77.6C27,-78.1,54.1,-62.4,68.3,-38.6Z");
    }
    50%{
        d : path("M65.4,-37C79.1,-14.1,80.5,16.6,67.5,37C54.6,57.5,27.3,67.8,0,67.8C-27.3,67.8,-54.6,57.5,-66.3,37.8C-78,18,-74.1,-11.3,-60.5,-34.2C-46.8,-57,-23.4,-73.5,1.2,-74.2C25.9,-74.9,51.8,-59.9,65.4,-37Z");
    }
    75%{
        d : path("M57.1,-35.2C68.5,-13.3,68.3,13,56.8,32.4C45.4,51.9,22.7,64.4,-1.4,65.2C-25.6,66.1,-51.2,55.2,-63,35.5C-74.9,15.9,-73,-12.6,-60.2,-35.3C-47.4,-58,-23.7,-74.9,-0.4,-74.7C22.9,-74.4,45.8,-57,57.1,-35.2Z");
    }
    100%{
        d : path("M67.2,-41.6C78.5,-19.4,72.9,9.7,58.9,34.3C44.8,58.9,22.4,78.9,-0.9,79.4C-24.2,79.9,-48.5,61,-59.4,38.2C-70.3,15.4,-67.9,-11.2,-55.8,-33.9C-43.6,-56.6,-21.8,-75.5,3.1,-77.2C28,-79,56,-63.8,67.2,-41.6Z");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-img col-lg-6">
                    <div class="blob">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="blob" width="600">
                            <path fill="#FE17A2" d="M59.1,-33.9C71.6,-12.5,73.4,15.4,61.7,35.4C50.1,55.4,25,67.5,-1.8,68.6C-28.7,69.6,-57.4,59.7,-69.8,39.2C-82.3,18.7,-78.5,-12.2,-64.1,-34.7C-49.8,-57.2,-24.9,-71.2,-0.8,-70.8C23.3,-70.3,46.6,-55.3,59.1,-33.9Z" transform="translate(100 100)" />
                        </svg>                              
                    </div>
                </div>
```